# Back button not responding ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I am newbie in iOS development and currently stuck on creating back button. I already placed **popViewControllerAnimated** method on tapping button, also I test it on debugging mode and back button method is calling but **popViewControllerAnimated** is not working.

Here is the code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.height-100), 30, 80, 20)];
    [backButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(BackButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:backButton];

    //some piece of code...

}//end of viewDidLoad method


-(void)BackButtonClicked: (id)sender{  
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"testing" message:@"some message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"NO", nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

On tapping back button this alert is showing but screen is not going back.

Any help regarding this issue will be highly appreciable.

I called this viewController by writing this code in my previous viewController

```
PlaceTranslatedDetailsViewController *secondViewController =
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"placeTranslatedDetail"];
[self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

However, this viewController and previous viewController were designed programmatically

Comment: whats your view controller pushed? how was it loaded and presented?

Comment: write code of present your viewcontroller

Comment: please review now, I made some changes in content of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]
```

Comment: currently screen is sliding down on tapping back button, is it possible to slide it to right side on tapping ?

Comment: It is recommended by Apple to keep the same route a screen enters and leaves. If it slides in from top it should dismiss to the top. You can do it differently, but for best effect keep the same

Answer (score 2):

If your `viewcontroller` is not an `rootviewcontroller` for a `uinavigationcontroller` than the method `popViewControllerAnimated` won't work. So you need to have a `uinavigationcontroller` behind in order to push/pop a `viewcontroller`.

So in your case you have to use `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` instead of `popViewController` because you presented modally a view controller.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. +1 for explaining the issue.

Comment: @Amar Thanks,it doesn't matter , I only hope he read what i explained here.

Answer (score 2):

You are not presenting your view controller as part of a navigation stack, so using `popViewControlleranimated:` is not going to work.

You need to use

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

A push (via `pushViewController` or storyboard push segue) will need a call to `popViewController`

A presented view (via `presentVewController` or a storyboard modal segue) needs a `dismissViewController` call.